# Remove tabs/spaces indentation check from VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to remove tab or spaces indentation in VS code?
I'm using VS Code and every time I write code I struggle a lot in indenting the code with the right spaces or tabs.

I want to know if it is possible to remove the indentation check from VS code.

Comment: Open the settings window in VSCode and type "tab" in the search box.

Comment: Just open the Settings and search for "Indent". There you have a lot of options.